# Improving urls in asp.net mvc2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

**Improving urls**

Currently I have links in the form (displaying product information):

http://localhost:XXXX/Products/?page=1

I want to clean this up into the form:

http://localhost:XXXX/Products/Page1

I think I need to do this with `routes.MapRoute`, something like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "/Products/Page{page}", new {controller = "ProductController", action = "Index"});
```

This was put above the default route (so should override I am led to believe)

The product controller looks like this:

```
    //
    // GET: /Products/
    public ActionResult Index([DefaultValue(1)] int page)
    {
        var productsToShow = //omitted for simplicity

        var viewModel = new ProductIndexViewModel
                            {
                                ProductList = //omitted for simplicity,
                                PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
                                                 {
                                                     CurrentPage = page,
                                                     ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                                                     TotalItems = productsToShow.Count()
                                                 }
                            };

        //Passed to view as ViewData.Model (or simply Model)
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `routes.MapRoute`

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "Products/Page{page}", new {controller = "Products", action = "Index"});
```

Comment: Correct - the *Convention* is that all controller classes END with the word `Controller`. As such, the routes then don't need you to add that full word into the route details, as above. So like @Akyegane says, controller = "Products" .. not "ProductsController"